# Java: Is this Singleton Class variable assignment thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

public class A {}

// 1. suppose Test is definitely a singleton, here skip singleton default impl

// 2. Test field a (class A) has no dirty value issue, or does it?

// 3. Singleton Object (ex, this sample) field assignment (in multi-threaded environment), has no race condition or deadlock issue, or does it?

```
public class Test
{

    private A a;

    public A get() {
        if (a == null) {
            a = new A();
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no deadlock, but it's absolutely not thread-safe. You could easily end up with multiple instances being created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not thread safe.

Suppose

1. Thread 1 called Test.get()
2. Thread 1 get() method checked (a == null) -> which is true
3. ---Context Switch Here---
4. Thread 2 called test.get()
5. Thread 2 get() method checked (a == null) -> which is true
6. Thread 2 get() method creates an A1 object and assigns it to a;
7. Thread 2 get() method returns A1
8. ---Context Switch Here---
9. Thread 1 get() method creates an A2 object and assigns it to a;
10. Thread 1 get() method returns A2

this means that two different threads got two different instances of class A

Hope this helps